# How to mock nested dependencies in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, sinon, proxyquire

I have a Module a

```
const b = require(./b);

function aGetResult() {
  return b.getInfo();
}
```

Module B

```
const c = require(./c);
    
function getInfo() {
  return getDetailInfo();
}

function getDetailInfo() {
    const result = c.getApiResult();
    return result
}
```

Module C

```
function getApiResult() {
  return api.get(/test/1);
}
```

I've written a test for module A but am running into an issue with stubbing dependencies.I just want to stub `c.getApiResult()` and not `b.getInfo()` or `b.getDetailInfo()`. I've tried selectively stubbing using `proxyquire` but am having issues. Any help?

Comment: You want to test module a and stub module c?

Comment: Yes, technically not a unit test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [Globally override require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire#globally-override-require) of `proxyquire` package.

`a` depends `b`, `b` depends on `c`. Now you want to mock the indirect `c`  dependency instead of direct `b` dependency when you test `a`. **It's NOT recommended to do this.** But anyway, here is the solution:

E.g.

`a.js`:

```js
const b = require('./b');

function aGetResult() {
  return b.getInfo();
}

exports.aGetResult = aGetResult;
```

`b.js`:

```js
const c = require('./c');

function getInfo() {
  return getDetailInfo();
}

function getDetailInfo() {
  const result = c.getApiResult();
  return result;
}

module.exports = { getInfo };
```

`c.js`:

```js
const api = {
  get(url) {
    return 'real result';
  },
};

function getApiResult() {
  return api.get('/test/1');
}

module.exports = { getApiResult };
```

`a.test.js`:

```js
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('63275147', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const stubs = {
      './c': {
        getApiResult: sinon.stub().returns('stubbed result'),
        '@global': true,
      },
    };
    const a = proxyquire('./a', stubs);
    const actual = a.aGetResult();
    expect(actual).to.be.eq('stubbed result');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(stubs['./c'].getApiResult);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  63275147
    ✓ should pass (2630ms)


  1 passing (3s)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   83.33 |      100 |      60 |   83.33 |                   
 a.js     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 b.js     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 c.js     |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 3-8               
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```